# XSL-FO SVG Format support - .Net

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, xsl-fo

I need to render svg in my XSL fo in c#.Net which is available in https://fonet.codeplex.com/. I tried to use svg in the xsl-fo but it does not render any pdf and fails silently.

If anybody has found a solution for this issue please help.

I need my pdf report to support svg contents.

Comment: The first entry in the FO.NET FAQ at https://fonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ states that it does not support SVG.  There are, of course, other XSL-FO formatters with a C# interface that do support SVG, such as AH Formatter.

Comment: Below answer does the trick for rendering svg in xsl-fo, you should look into it.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK Please, could you provide more info? which DLL library are you using in this example? I guess this one: archive.codeplex.com/?p=svg Also in your example, they are objects like Constants.*, ICacheService, HttpCache, Path.Combine, which I do not know to which assembly they belong to. Could you indicate to which assembly they belong to?

Comment: I will send u stripped code tommorow

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK Ok, thanks a lot. I will highly appreciate you. I need in NET Framework 3.5. My app is not a web app. It is a windows forms app in C#. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code to add Hander of an image incase of svg extensions

```
 FonetDriver fonetDriver = FonetDriver.Make();
 fonetDriver.ImageHandler = SvgImageHandler;
```

Add the SvgImageHandler Hander

```
 private static byte[] SvgImageHandler(string svgContent)
        {
            if (svgContent.Contains("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"))
            {
                var svgByteAry = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svgContent);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(svgByteAry))
                {
                    var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(stream);
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        svgDocument.Draw()
                                   .Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        return byteArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Skip if not url based image
            if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(svgContent, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                return null;

            if (!ValidateUrlImage(svgContent))
            {
                ICacheService cacheService = new HttpCache();
                return cacheService.Get(Constants.NoImage,
                                        () =>
                                        {
                                            var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.ImagePath];
                                            var defaultUrl = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, Constants.NoImageFile);
                                            var img = Image.FromFile(defaultUrl);
                                            var imgCon = new ImageConverter();
                                            return (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
                                        });
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Return proper image if the url is valid or pass false so the No Image can be rendered. keeping the code more robust.

```
private static bool ValidateUrlImage(string absoluteUrl)
        {
            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(absoluteUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                return true;
            }
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(uri))
                    {
                        Image.FromStream(stream);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, could you provide more info? which DLL library are you using in this example? I guess this one: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=svg Also in your example, they are objects like Constants.*, ICacheService, HttpCache, Path.Combine, which I do not know to which assembly they belong to. Could you indicate to which assembly they belong to?