# Rendering XSL-Fo document into PDF and then into byte array using Fonet

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xsl-fo

I have a XSL-Fo document which I am trying to parse to PDF and finally, this PDF to a byte array using [Fonet](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fonet) DLL but it does not work.

I do not want to render it into a temporary file, instead I want to render it into memory and then convert it into a byte array.

Below the code:

```
Fonet.FonetDriver fo = new Fonet.FonetDriver();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlFo);

byte[] bytArray;
using (MemoryStream oStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    fo.Render(xml, oStream);
    bytArray = oStream.ToArray();
}
```

xmlFo is a string containing the XSL-Fo document. When rendering into MemoryStream below exception is raised:

> System.SystemException: Unknown formatting object
>   http://www.w3.org/2000/svg^svg\r\n   at
>   Fonet.FonetDriver.FireFonetError(String message)\r\n   at
>   Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.StartElement(String uri, String localName,
>   Attributes attlist)\r\n   at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.Parse(XmlReader
>   reader)

Comment: It seems like SVG Vector graphics are not supported in FO.NET... https://github.com/prepare/FO.NET/wiki/1.2-FO.NET-FAQ

Comment: I have found this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218571/xsl-fo-svg-format-support-net that is based on this DLL: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=svg My problem is that in the first link, the example (solution) provided has some objects like Constants.NoImage, Constants.NoImageFile, Constants.ImagePath, ICacheService and HttpCache that I do not know to which assembly they belong to, so they are not recognized by c# compiler. What assembly they belong to?Any help?